# $u:E\to F$ is linear map between vector spaces. If $E$ or $F$ finite dimensional, then $u$ is compact? How?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

This is related to Lang, Real and Functional Analysis Chpt XVII, sec 1.

"$u:E\to F$ is linear map between vector spaces. If $E$ or $F$ finite dimensional, then $u$ is compact."

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why is above true when $F$ is finite dimensional? When $E$ is finite dimensional, it follows trivially. If it is just linear map, consider $R^{N}\to R$ where $N$ is natural number cardinality as the following. Given basis $e_i$ of $R^{N}$, send $e_i\to i\in R$. Equip $R^N$ with sup norm and $R$ with absolute value. Clearly I can extend this map to a linear map for $R^N\to R$. This is not continuous and it can't be compact. Is there anything wrong with this or I missed something here? The compact operator is defined as if $u$ takes bounded set to pre-compact set in the target and there is no requirement for continuity as compact implies continuity automatically.

Comment: I think that you're right. is Lang only supposing that $u$ is a linear map? Is he not supposing that $u$ is a linar operator?

Comment: Just checking based on your last sentence:  Do you believe that the image of the unit step function, $\{0,1\}$, being compact makes the unit step function continuous?  (I expect you intend additional condition(s) in that sentence.)

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Lang says "Let $E,F$ be normed vector spaces and $u:E\to F$ be a linear map." We say $u$ compact if $u$ maps bounded sets of $E$ to relatively compact sets of $F$... Example. If $E$ or $F$ is finite dimensional, then $u$ is compact..." The book is not even assuming this is a linear operator.

Comment: @EricTowers I should say compact linear implies continuity instead.

Answer (score 1):

If $u$ is assumed merely linear, then it may not be compact.(There should be abundance of examples, for instance if $X$ is infinite dimensional Banach space over $\mathbb{R}$ then $X$ possess unbounded linear functionals, and so cannot be compact)

However $u$ is compact if continuity is assumed at the first place.